# Add a material to a Mesh in THREEJS

Tags: javascript, three.js, mesh

How do I add a material to an existing mesh -

I do not want to call the mesh constructor again - is there a way?

I'm talking about - I have a mesh, I already called the constructor like this

```
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
```

now I created more materials in code:

```
    var material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
```

and now I want to add it to the mesh

```
    mesh.material = [material, material2]; //does not work
```

this doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

OK so I found the answer - it does actually work - just make sure you pass the whole array to the mesh - and don't try to do something like

```
    mesh.material = someArray.map(function(item){return 
    item.material;});
```

Which is what I was doing - also strange things happen if don't clone materials and store them into variables first before using them..

or it could be a browser related issue - who knows - strange things happen sometimes..

Comment: "the whole array" ?

Comment: "Which is what I was doing " why didn't you post that in the question? It's not what you were doing you were doing an array literal